# Convert Imperial to Metric in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, metric

Yes I have seen [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325116/613858) But it's for php. I'm still new to programming and was surprised there wasn't a iOS question posted for this. This is how I'm converting from decimal to fraction. Thought it may help with the formatting for Imperial to Metric. So the question is how would I go about converting from imperial to metric in iOS?

```
//Converts Decimals to Fractions.
- (NSString *)DecToFrac:(float)input {

NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"",@"",@"1/8",@"",@"1/4",@"",@"3/8",@"",@"1/2",@"",@"5/8",@"",@"3/4",@"",@"3/4",@"",@"7/8",@"",nil];

int fractions = lroundf((input - (int)input)/((float)1/(float)16));
if(fractions == 0 || fractions == 16) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d''",lroundf(input)];
} else {
    if([[array objectAtIndex:fractions] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d/16''",(int)input,fractions];
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@''",(int)input,[array objectAtIndex:fractions]];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: With the formatting I have above, is there a method to convert imperial measurements to Metric?

Comment: It really depends on which imperial measurements and which metric measurements....

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is a method to call once I have the measurement, I can hit a button to convert back and forth.

Comment: This is really an algorithm question, not iOS specific...there is no iOS specific way to do basic arithmetic.  Plus...WHAT MEASUREMENT?  I've never heard of something being "5 imperials" or "7 metrics."

Comment: I put iOS because I'm looking for the correct syntax. I'm not sure why everyone's asking "What Measurement." Any measurement in the format i have above.Like 09ft 03 5/16in is how the above would display. And I only know of 1 imperial and 1 metric...forgive my ignorance if I'm not understanding what your asking for, seems very clear to me what I'm asking. Perhaps I need more detail on what you need from me?

Comment: @Jason: if you cannot name a specific measurement, then your question is too broad.  Try to focus on one aspect at a time.  Is this app for measuring, cooking, landscaping, etc. and figure out which conversion is most important, then use it as a template.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think about cooking, ha. For building, like carpentry.

Comment: So... How about something small then... Say; inches to centimeters and back again?  I can work with that.

Comment: ok, that should help get me started, I just have to see the code, then I'm able to see how it works, that's how I learn. Sorry for not being clear, I just think of measurements as building something. Not much of a cook! ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most conversions are simply arithmetic problems, iOS should be able to handle anything you give it just fine.  To use my example of inches to centimeters maybe try:

```
-(float)centimetersToInches:(float)centimeters {
    float inches = centimeters/2.54;
    return inches;
}
```

Everything else is a matter of storing which formula goes with which pairing.