# Generate Weight & Height Array PHP

Tags: php

How do I create a php function that calculates, and then generates an array that represents both imperial, and its equivalent metric measurements(for humans) for any given range(say 4ft to 7ft)?.

For example:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 4'8"(142cm)
    [2] => 4'9"(144.5cm)
    [3] => 4'10"(147cm)
)
```

...and so on. The same example for weight(pounds/kilos) also. If someone could give me a head start on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What actually do you expect from community? The conversion is a pretty straightforward (trivial math), the array generation is trivial as well (`foreach` or `for`)

Comment: @zerkms As unhelpful, and somewhat rude as your comment seems, you may be right in that this is a trivial thing - for you. However, for me the case is not the same. I can't get my head around what is the best way to achieve this. This is a question, in a community that answers them. If it is so trivial, teach me something, and gain yourself some points and a good feeling inside that you helped someone today instead of being critical of my perception of this community, and judgmental of my abilities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert imperial units of length into metric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325116/how-to-convert-imperial-units-of-length-into-metric)

Comment: @Lea: well, split your issue to a smaller ones. Let's say the first one: generate a row of numbers. Another one: assuming the number is a length in feet - convert it to meters. Which one of these are you in stuck with? **Every** problem in programming consists of smaller ones. And every programmer just solves small issues one by one iteratively. PS: I asked what you expect from us because your current question looks like: "This is a task, please do that for me"

Comment: @zerkms I asked for a head start at the bottom of my question, and not to be "spoon fed". The question is explicit, and asks "How?", and not "Can someone do this...?". I'm looking for ideas on how to achieve this, having not done it before, I'm stumped as to where to begin, can't find discussions regarding it. Have probably made it all more complicated in my head, and just needed a little push in the right direction. I'll take your advice and try to break down everything, and start from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might point you in the right direction.. have not tested but it should be enough to get you started. very simple concept. I got you started with the feet+ inches strings - now you should be able figure out how to get the meters in there.

```
// $startHeight and $endHeight are in inches

function createRange($startHeight,$endHeight){

// calculate the difference in inches between the heights
$difference = $endHeight - $startHeight;

// create an array to put the results in
$resultsArray; 

//create a loop with iterations = $difference

for($i=0;$i<$difference;$i++)
{
    // create the current height based on the iteration
    $currentHeight = $startHeight + $i;

    // convert the $currentHeight to feet+inches
    // first find the remainder, which will be the inches
    $remainder = ($currentHeight % 12);
    $numberOfFeet = ($currentHeight - $remainder)/12;

    // build the feet string
    $feetString = $numberOfFeet.'&apos;'.$remainder.'&quot;';

    // now build the meter string using a similar method as above
    // and append it to $feetString, using a conversion factor

    // add the string to the array
    $resultsArray[] = $feetString;

}

// return the array
return $resultsArray;

}
```